# Child property in parent component won't update

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm trying to get access of the child property menuType. I have some code so far, but somehow the parent isn't updating the property along with its child component.

This is my approach:

**Parent:**

```
import {AfterViewInit, Component, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import { MenuHeaderComponent } from './menu-header/menu-header.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-menu',
  templateUrl: './menu.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./menu.component.scss']
})
export class MenuComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild(MenuHeaderComponent) menuTypeDetail: MenuHeaderComponent;
  menuType: number;

  constructor() { }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.getChildProperty();
  }

  getChildProperty(): void {
    this.menuType = this.menuTypeDetail.menuType;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

**Child:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-menu-header',
  templateUrl: './menu-header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./menu-header.component.scss']
})
export class MenuHeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  menuType = 3;

  menuClicked(type): void {
    this.menuType = type;
  }

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Comment: Any reason you're using `@ViewChild()` instead of `@Output()`? If not, you should be using `@Output()`. Otherwise, your TS looks fine. Can you include the HTML of both though? Might be missing something there.

Comment: Use a service which will update and keep the value both in parent in child in sync.

Comment: If a parent component needs to keep a property in sync with a child, the child component needs to output the value via an `@Output()` when it changes. https://angular.io/guide/architecture-components#data-binding